# aria-* attributes do not have valid values

Tags: html, wai-aria

I'm running tests with Lighthouse on [this page](https://www.localizzazionemezzi.it/la-piattaforma).

When it comes to Accessibility, it keeps give me this error:

> [aria-*] attributes do not have valid values.
>   Assistive technologies, like screen readers, can't interpret ARIA attributes with invalid values.

The code that causes that error is:

```html
<button role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="v-pills-home" id="v-pills-home-tab" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-login"><img src="./images/come-funziona/iconLogin.png" width="60" alt="login"> Login</button>

<button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" id="v-pills-profile-tab" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-localizzazione"><img src="./images/come-funziona/iconLocalizzazione.png" width="60" alt="localizzazione mezzi"> Localizzazione</button>

<button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" id="v-pills-messages-tab" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-badge"><img src="./images/come-funziona/iconBadgeRFID.png" width="60" alt="badge rfid"> Badge</button>

<button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" id="v-pills-settings-tab" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-manutenzione"><img src="./images/come-funziona/iconManutenzione.png" width="60" alt="manutenzione mezzi"> Manutenzione</button>

<button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="v-pills-reports" id="v-pills-report-tab" class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-report"><img src="./images/come-funziona/iconReport.png" width="60" alt="report attività mezzi"> Report</button>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Check what are the valid values for `aria-selected` and `aria-controls` for Lighthouse. They should have documentation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have three ARIA related attributes so let's go through all three.

1. `tab` is a valid `role` and the `<button>` element is allowed to have that role.  (See the [`<button>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#ref-for-allowed-aria-role-attribute-values%E2%91%A0%E2%93%AA%E2%91%A4) spec - `tab` is the last one in the list.)
2. `aria-selected` is only valid on certain types of objects, but `tab` is one of them so you're ok there.  And the valid values are `true` and `false`, so that's ok too.  (See the [`aria-selected`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-selected) spec.)
3. `aria-controls` should contain an id, or list of ids.  Your example looks like it contains an id.  Does the referred to object exist?  When I viewed your test page, the first button/tab says it controls `v-pills-home` but I didn't see that object on the page.  The tabpanel for the first button/tab has an id of `v-pills-login`.  The same problem happens on the other buttons too.  They all point to an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I changed them and now they works.

Comment: why do they need to exist? Can the controlled elements not be inserted dynamically into the DOM when the controlling element is interacted with?

Comment: `> why do they need to exist?` - because that's what the spec says.  if you try https://validator.w3.org/nu/ (the official w3c validator), change "check by" to "text input" and try to validate `<button aria-controls="fooID">bar</button>`, it'll fail with `Error: The aria-controls attribute must point to an element in the same document`.  if you dynamically create the element that is controlled, then dynamically add `aria-controls` once the element exists.